# Wait until a method finish

Tags: unity, c#

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database and I'm trying to compare if a name is available to other user. The problem is the method finish before the Firebase's method finish its execution. Here is the code:

```
private bool IsNameAvailable (string nick) 
{
    bool available = false;
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference ("users").OrderByChild ("name").EqualTo (nick).GetValueAsync ().ContinueWith (task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted) {
            Debug.LogError ("A error encountered: " + task.Exception);
        } else if (task.IsCanceled) {
            Debug.LogError ("Canceled ...");
        } else if (task.IsCompleted) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            available = (snapshot.GetValue (true) == null);
        }
    });
    return available; //This line executed before the Firebase's method end.
}
```

What can i do??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preventing that method from continuing until the Firebase database has returned a value would be a bad idea, because it would freeze the whole game process. So a function `bool IsNameAvailable (string nick)` is simply not going to work when it needs to access a remote resource. You will have to work with asynchronously called callback-methods in this case. There is really no good way around it.

That means you don't have a `IsNameAvailable` method which returns `bool`, you have one which returns `void` and receives a method as an additional parameter which gets called as soon as it got a result from the database.

So instead of this code:

```
 if (IsNameAvailable (nick) ) {
    textlabel.text = "Name is available";
 } else {
    textlabel.text = "Name is already taken";
 }
```

You will have to pass a callback-method to `IsNameAvailable` which gets executed as soon as the database is finished:

```
 IsNameAvailable (nick, NameCheckCallback);

 /*...*/

 private void NameCheckCallback(bool success) {
     if (success) {
        textlabel.text = "Name is available";
     } else {
        textlabel.text = "Name is already taken";
     }
 }
```

Your `IsNameAvailable` function would then look like this:

```
private void IsNameAvailable (string nick, Action<bool> callbackFunction) 
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference ("users").OrderByChild ("name").EqualTo (nick).GetValueAsync ().ContinueWith (task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted) {
            Debug.LogError ("A error encountered: " + task.Exception);
        } else if (task.IsCanceled) {
            Debug.LogError ("Canceled ...");
        } else if (task.IsCompleted) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            callbackFunction(snapshot.GetValue(true) == null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! (I forgot to thanks you before, but that answer help me a lot!)